# Using the javascript fetch api to perform a POST request

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I would like to reproduce the behavior of this cURL request :

```
➜  % curl --data "" https://api.t411.ch/auth
{"error":"User not found","code":101}
```

In this case, the server send me back JSON.

The code I use in Javascript is :

```
fetch('https://api.t411.ch/auth/', {
    method: 'POST'
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(datas => {
  console.log(datas);
});
```

With that, I get a parsing json error, so, I decided to return `response.text()` instead of `response.json()`

The `console.log(datas)` prints : `string(5) "1.2.4" Service 'view' wasn't found in the dependency injection container`

It's the same string that I get when I access to the url : https://api.t411.ch/auth with my browser (GET request).

That means that my javascript code send a GET request, even with the `method: 'post'`

What am I doing bad ?

PS: I think it's not related at all, but I use es6/jsx transpiled by babel in an electron project.

Thanks

Comment: Word of warning: this is experimental javascript and poorly supported. Don't use it for anything other than fiddling around, just use a standard `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Getting a security warning when clicking that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to POST to `https://api.t411.ch/auth/`. It should be `https://api.t411.ch/auth` instead. This should work fine:

```
fetch('https://api.t411.ch/auth', {
    method: 'POST'
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(datas => {
  console.log(datas);
});
```

Comment: oh, thanks ! And say that I spent over two hours for a "/".